# Using cURL to Access Url, then Submit Data

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to:

1. access `$url`
2. Insert the (2) values, of the two indices into the corresponding input fields (username,password) then submitting.
3. finally grab the response from inputting and submitting in #2 and outputting the response.

I have the following code:

```
  <?php
# get url to form
$url = "http://localhost/exploitme2/index.php?page=login.php";
$ch = curl_init($url); # initialize that form

#run value of $_POST variable in form fields from above url.
$params = array("'' or '1'='1'", "'' or '1'='1'");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);  #set parameter $_POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

## echo the result from cURL 'ing
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I get this error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
```

on this line:

```
$params = array($_POST['username']=>'' or '1'='1', 
                $_POST['password']=>'' or '1'='1');
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a script to brute force a login form? The word `expolitme2` sets off a red flag for me =o\

Comment: Eventually, in a white-hat sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In technical terms, this is all just 1 step operation and not 3. You have already completed all those 3 steps. When you post those values to the above url then your result will be stored in your $result variable as per your code, just need to return / display it. for cURL it is not like you have to visit a url first and then submit next, if you know the field names and the action url then you can do all those 3 things in 1 step like you have already done

try an echo for this variable

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
**echo $result;**
curl_close($ch);
```

Ok let me clearify some confusions here

**1)** You don't have to specify the variables in $_POST array. Your cURL POST variables can be any. They don't have to be in $_POST.

**2)** You have to post the data to the form's **action** url and not its own url, (unless ofcourse both are same)

**So for 1 your code should be like**

```
$params = array("'' or '1'='1'", "'' or '1'='1'");
```

Comment: Mind showing a code sample here? I appreciate the understanding you've provided so far.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. My array value's for $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] wont work because the actual value I'm trying to input is *** ' or '1'='1  *** but the single quotes are throwing it off. How can I do this?

Comment: please see updated code, it now will not load the page at all stating: "The connection was reset"